# React Native Expo - Complex Video Component

Tags: javascript, video, react-native, components, expo

guys!

Do you know if there is any video component for Expo that I can use and has pause/play & fullscreen options that really work?

I've been looking for something like that for a day and couldn't find anything like it working.

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Which version of Expo you are using?

Comment: @RodrigoChaves, now I'm using the latest version of Expo and I've made my own VideoPlayer component using Video / AV from expo

Comment: @TrabajoPapito Do you mind sharing some of your findings with the community?